# Check if two layers are identical in Google Earth Engine - Is a visual inspection useful?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I made a copy of an Image that was shared with me as an asset in Google Earth Engine.

I expect the new copy to be identical to the image that was shared. To check that nothing was changed during export, I made a new image that is the difference between my two images, and I expect the result to be an image with uniform zero value.

```
var original = ee.Image("..."); //shared layer
var copy = ee.Image("...");

var difference = original.subtract(copy)
```

However, if I add `difference` to the map, it shows a pattern if I take a look from far away:
[image]

Inspecting the value of pixels shows values other than zero.

However, the pattern fades away if I zoom in, and I only find zeros if I inspect pixel values. I've added some transparency to the layer in the capture, but you can see that it's a plain grey.
[image]

Still, if I print the properties of my `difference` layer, it shows -255 and 255 as min and max values.

I think this is something about how GEE works with pyramids or pixel representation at different zoom scales.
Indeed, the original and copy layers also look a bit different from the distance, but they look the same from close distance:

original

[image]

copy

[image]

I'll zoom in to the island where the arrow points

original

[image]

copy

[image: copy]

**Can I trust that the two layers are identical in their values and their difference is zero for every pixel?**

Comment: I've seen this too and haven't found a trivial solution. An exhaustive one would be to run reduceRegions with an appropriate reducer on the difference image over a large area, but that takes time. Another thing to check are the image properties. Are the dimensions the same? Are the transform values the same?

Comment: try to add the difference layer to the map reprojected to the orignal image projection. `var proj = original.projection()` and then `Map.addLayer(difference.reproject(proj)....)`. If that works I post it as an answer

Comment: Rodrigo, that didn't do the trick. I see where you are going, but I checked and the projections where the same before comparing them. Thanks for the suggestion thought!

Comment: I have explored them further and, looking closely, the difference seems to be zero elsewhere. So I think it's a problem with how are piramids calculated. They are probably calculated in different ways, and that gives differences at other scales.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do a frequency histogram of the values in your "difference image", over your region of interest? You should only find 0 values.

Such test would not be dependent on projection, though could eventually be dependent on the `scale` argument, facing the trade-off of faster (coarse scale to avoid the max pixel issue) versus precision (fine scale).

```
var checkit2 = difference.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry: ageometry,
  scale: 1000
})
```